# Count the frequency of concecutive zeros in a every time they appear in a each row

Tags: r, arrays, dataframe, sorting, slice

*I have this dataframe and would like to compute a count of zero sequences every time they appear in a row so that the output would be A: 2 4, B:1 2 1, C:2 5, D: 2 3, E: 1 1*

```
df <- data.frame(
A=c(1,  0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0), 
B=c(0,  1,  1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  1),
C=c(0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0), 
D=c(0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0),
E=c(1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  1,  1)
)
```

Comment: I would like to do this in dplyr or base R

Answer (score 2):

We may use `rle` by looping over the columns of the `data.frame` and get the `lengths` of the 0 values in `base R`

```
lapply(df1, function(x) with(rle(x), lengths[!values]))
```

-output

```
$A
[1] 2 4

$B
[1] 1 2 1

$C
[1] 2 5

$D
[1] 2 3

$E
[1] 1 1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), B = c(0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1), C = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), D = c(0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), E = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @magwabat you may have an older R version.  Change the `\(x)` to `function(x)` and it will work

Comment: Thank you for the answer to my question

Comment: When I run the code, I get this       
Error: unexpected input in "lapply(df1, \"                                                                      "Any idea why I have this error?"

Comment: ```df1 <- structure(list(A = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), B = c(0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1), C = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), D = c(0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), E = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = "data.frame")``` constructing a data frame this way is possile with limited entries. My data though have hundreds of rows and column. I thried the following but i didnt wrk

Comment: ```df1 <- structure(list(df)), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = "data.frame")```

Comment: @magwabat it is very easy.  You need just `dput(df)`, the output is this structure.  The reason I use this is to make sure that anybody who copies this gives the exact structure I used instead of somebody posting an image or even using data.frame call (depends on `stringsAsFactors` etc.)

Comment: Thanks , let me try

Comment: @magwabat `df` is also a function name (in case you haven't already created 'df' object in the env.  easier to check is `dput(head(mtcars))`